# Using a JAR dependency in a PySpark parallelized execution context

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

This is for a PySpark / Databricks project:

I've written a Scala JAR library and exposed its functions as UDFs via a simple Python wrapper; everything works as it should in my PySpark notebooks. However, when I try to use any of the functions imported from the JAR in an `sc.parallelize(..).foreach(..)` environment, execution keeps dying with the following error:

```
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

at this line in the wrapper:

```
jc = get_spark()._jvm.com.company.package.class.get_udf(function.__name__)
```

My suspicious is that the JAR library is not available in the parallelized context, since if I replace the library path to some gibberish, the error remains exactly the same.

I haven't been able to find the necessary clues in the Spark docs so far. Using an `sc.addFile("dbfs:/FileStore/path-to-library.jar")` didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the JAR in the `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` environment variable (before Spark 2.3 this was doable with `SPARK_CLASSPATH` as well).

For example with:

`os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars <path/to/jar> pyspark-shell'`